# Soundplayer for compiled application

Tags: c#, compilation, embedded-resource, soundplayer

How can I hardcode the code in order to pull the .wav file from the project?

As well as where should I put the .wav file?

[image]

The code I am currently using is:

```
        private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SoundPlayer simpleSound = new SoundPlayer(@"c:\Windows\Media\dj.wav");
        simpleSound.Play();
    }
```

I just want the path @"c:\Windows\Media\dj.wav" to be for that content folder... So that when I deploy the application to another computer it comes with it....

Answer (score 1):

Use `GetManifestResourceStream`.

```cs
var path = "MyApplicationNamespace.Content.dj.wav";
var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

using( var soundStream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream( path ) )
using( var soundPlayer = new SoundPlayer( soundStream ) )
{
    soundPlayer.Play();
}
```

The string passed to `GetManifestResourceStream` must be fully qualified with your application's root namespace and the directory tree the wave file resides in.

You also need to set the `Build Action` for the wave file to `Embedded Resource` in the properties window.